# SSIM loss with possibly negative input

Tags: loss-functions, image-processing

I have a regression task (image reconstruction) and the benchmark was done using L1Loss (Pytorch). The input images were normalised to [-1, 1] so that tanh activation could be used. When I tried switching the loss to perceptual SSIM loss from piqa, I get an error, since the input can be negative due to the normalisation.

A possible solution is to change normalisation to [0, 1] range and use it together with sigmoid activation, but I am wondering if there is a way around it, i.e. is there a way to use SSIM loss together with tanh?

Comment: did you find any solution?